# How can I get the last value from a table using the generator with the best performance

Tags: sql, firebird, firebird2.5

I want to get the last ID from table Client with the best performance without using MAX(). I have an ASC index for ID. I'm considering that my generator has a higher value than the last ID so I'm using this select:

```
SELECT FIRST 1 c.id FROM client c WHERE c.id <= GEN_ID(GEN_CLIENT_ID,0)
```

This select returns the first id from the table, I'm pretty sure that if I use AND after this select, I can get the last id, I just don't know how to do it.

I know that if I use ORDER BY DESC, I can get what I want, but it will not use the index and it will read all the values on the table.

I'm using Firebird 2.5.

Comment: Why do you want the last ID? Because this sounds a bit like an [XY problem](https://xyproblem.info/). For example, if it is to get the id of a record you just inserted, then using the `RETURNING` clause of the `INSERT` statement is the better solution. Also, selecting a ID this way may not get you the actual last id (things will depend on the transaction settings of your session, and whether or not there are other concurrent transaction that haven't been committed yet).

Comment: Also, would you object to adding a descending index on ID, and if you object to that, why?

Comment: `I know that if I use ORDER BY DESC, I can get what I want, but it will not use the index` - this is untrue. It would use `descending index` and would not use `ascending index`. But absolutely same is true with `ORDER BY ASC` - it would equally use ascending index and would equally fail to use descending index.